# Binding XDocument to TreeView - attributes don't show up

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, bind, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I try to bind `XDocument` to `TreeView` control. Everything works fine excepting attributes. #%*!$#@^% don't want to show up:D

Please, help me to modify that code to make it work:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="xmlValueBrush" Color="Blue" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="xmAttributeBrush" Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="xmlTagBrush" Color="DarkMagenta" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="xmlMarkBrush" Color="Blue" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="AttributeTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            Margin="3,0,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
             Foreground="{StaticResource xmAttributeBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
        <TextBlock Text="=&quot;"
             Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
             Foreground="{StaticResource xmlValueBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
        <TextBlock Text="&quot;"
             Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Focusable="False">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Text="Root" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
        <ItemsControl
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AttributeTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attributes}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Path="Elements" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Text">
            <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
            <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

My `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="XmlTree" Grid.Row="1"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Root.Elements, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"
      SelectedItemChanged="XmlTree_SelectedItemChanged" />
```

It's my code behind:

```
private void BindXmlData(string filePath)
{
    _xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);
    XmlTree.DataContext = _xml;
}
```

All the nodes display well, but I can't manage with attributes to make them visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change your DataTriggers Sections from:

```
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </DataTrigger>
```

To:

```
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name.LocalName}" />
            </DataTrigger>
```

Hope will help, thanks! - Shams

Answer (score 0):

As answer did not work for me, I would like to hint to Ashs Answer ([Get XML Attributes in WPF with a treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788315/get-xml-attributes-in-wpf-with-a-treeview/49791733791733)).

In the original code given here I found another problem. Values of nodes are not rendered in the tree view.
for this to work I needed to remove the first DataTrigger and add another one. so the part

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
```

looks like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FirstNode.NodeType}" Value="Text">
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} = {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                            <Binding Path="FirstNode.Value"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Now each node containing a Value is rendered as:
Node-Name = Value